# Need a Regex to Parse This Line 58.21 -13.73 57 -1

Tags: regex, string, lua

Need help parsing the numbers from this line in Lua.

```
58.21 -13.73 57 -1
```

I currently am at this: `[1-9][0-9]` which I know is not correct as it does not return the minus and does not handle the decimal.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: What you mean by parsing? `.*` matches this line ;-)

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s="58.21 -13.73 57 -1"
for w in s:gmatch("%S+") do print(w) end
```

This pattern extracts all words from a line, a word being a run of non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for regex. Here is the simple implementation in python:

```
>>> s = '58.21 -13.73 57 -1'
>>> [float(i) for i in s.split()]
[58.21, -13.73, 57.0, -1.0]
```

The principle however is universal: split on space and convert to numeric type if necessary.

Comment: but you have added extra `.0` into the integers.

Comment: @ghostdog: are you for real? I've converted them into floats, if OP means something else by parsing then it needs to be stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua:

```
(%-?%d+%.?%d+)%s+(%-?%d+%.?%d+)%s+(%-?%d+%.?%d+)%s+(%-?%d+%.?%d+)
```

Example:

```
local a, b, c, d = ("58.21 -13.73 57 -1"):match(
    "(%-?%d+%.?%d*)%s+(%-?%d+%.?%d*)%s+(%-?%d+%.?%d*)%s+(%-?%d+%.?%d*)"
  )
print(a, b, c, d) --> 58.21 -13.73  57  -1
```

You may (or may not) want to convert returned values to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "parse" you mean, you want a Regular Expression that will match a number. In the string you provided, you would want the matches to be:

- 58.21
- -13.73
- 57
- -1

The pattern I would probably use is `([^ ]+)`. It will find anything except for space, which, in your string, would be numbers with (potentially) decimal points and signs.